# Building a Function with saddle point that has Certain Properties

Tags: multivariable-calculus, soft-question

I'm working on a problem and I'd like to compute a couple examples. For one example I'd like to create a function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:

1. It has a saddle at zero
2. It goes to positive infinity on the x AND y axis (so maybe cross sections along these axes are upward opening parabolas)
3. It goes to negative infinity along the line $x = y$ AND $x = -y$ (so maybe cross sections along these axes are downward opening parabolas).

What is an example of a function with such properties?

Thanks!

Comment: A degree $2$ polynomial obviously won't do.  Have you tried a degree $4$ polynomial?

Comment: Haha, nope. I'm totally lost on what should I guess.

Comment: Here's a hint: Have you played with a monkey saddle? It only has three directions of interest, not four, but understanding this might give you an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the commentor, I searched Monkey Saddles. I found more complicated saddles: I guess these types of surfaces are called n-th order saddles.

Formulas for them can be found here:
https://rivix.com/download/Docs/Peckham_2011_Saddles_Final.pdf

For my particular problem:
$f(x,y) = x^4 - 6x^2y^2 +y^4$